# How to backup passwords stored by Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I have Google Chrome (on Windows 7/8/Mac OS/iPhone/iPad) storing all my web passwords and sync'ing it far and wide. So far so good. However, I also wanted to keep a backup of the passwords in a clear text file which in turn lives on my truecrypt encrypted volume. How can I make this cleartext text-only backup of Chrome passwords?

PS: I do see [how it's stored](https://superuser.com/questions/146742/how-does-google-chrome-store-passwords) but I'm asking for how to backup it up as a cleartext file in an OS agnostic manner so I can (mount the truecrypt volume and) just open it up in a text editor and see the passwords.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, [Chromepass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html) is portable, trivially easy to use, and will let you save all passwords to a text file.

Comment: When I tried to extract the ChromePass folder, AVG gave me a warning saying it contained the advertising malware HackTool. I had previously downloaded it without that warning though.