# Recover Google Chrome passwords

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, encryption, passwords

I know google chrome stores passwords in: "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data" and to decrypt the passwords, I need to use the same user password of the system and need to operate on the same computer. What if I need to reinstall win10 and want to recover the passwords from "Login Data"? Can I just backup the "Login Data" file and then decrypt it in the reinstalled system with the same user account & passwords?

But from the comments in this questions: [Comment of Answer for "Decrypt Google Chrome passwords"](https://superuser.com/questions/655573/decrypt-google-chrome-passwords). It seems that it is not enough to just backup "Login Data" and create the same user account. So what else do I need to backup? What else do I need to do?

Background of the problem: My Win10 broke and I could not enter the system (even with safe mode). Now I have to reinstall the Win10 systems which will delete all my chrome passwords. Since I have a dual system Ubuntu and could access the windows files from Ubuntu, I can backup the "Login Data". I hope to recover the passwords after reinstalling win10.

Comment: The linked question’s answer is still accurate.  The chrome user data will be encrypted.

Comment: I know the data will be encrypted and the linked question's answer says it could be decrypted. And my question is how to decrypted (to be exact, whether it is enough to backup Login Data and use the same account , which proves not enough from the comment). I don't think I ask the same question. Could you explain more?